# Unchecked exception

Tags: java, exception, unchecked

I try to Create a custom unchecked exception class called InvalidDateException.  This exception class must include a constructor that takes a String as an argument. But I wonder is my code is custom unchecked exception or not.

```
class InvalidDateException extends RuntimeException
{
      //Parameterless Constructor
      public WordContainsException() {}  

      //Constructor that accepts a message
      public InvalidDateException(String message)
      {
         super(message);
      }
 }
```

Comment: In order to create a unchecked exception, you must extend RuntimeException.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But is it a unchecked exception??

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6115896/773623)

Comment: When you have an unchecked exception, you are not required to use try-catch.

Comment: Sorry my java skill is very bad. If you want to aswer the question, you can upload your code too.

Answer (score 4):

Since your class extends [`Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html), it's a **checked** exception. If you want to create an **unchecked** exception, you should extend [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).

Comment: @2h2h2h yup. You're golden.

Comment: thanks a lot mate, I try to accept your answer but it won't let me

Comment: @2h2h2h You need to [wait 15 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer) before you can accept an answer.

Comment: I just change my code will it still a unchecked exception with an constructor that takes a String as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your Exception class is a unchecked exception class as you have already extend with RuntimeException.